# Azure Service Bus - Delete Scheduled Messages from Topic

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I went through a couple of examples that states that the scheduled messages in the azure service bus can be deleted from queue, May I know if the scheduled messages can be deleted from the topic?

This is the scenario that I'm trying to solve.

1. Sender publishes scheduled messages on the topic
2. Sender publishes another set of standard messages to the queue.
3. I would like to read the messages from the queue using a listener/azure function and check if the same messages are scheduled in the topic and delete them from the schedule.
4. One or more subscriptions will listen to the messages from the topic based on filters when the time delay of the scheduled messages expires.
5. Azure function/Listener will read the messages from the subscriptions for downstream processing

Also, while reading the scheduled messages from the topic, can I apply any kind of filtering as the volume of scheduled messages in the topic would be very high.

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel scheduled messages from topics via [`TopicClient.CancelScheduledMessageAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.topicclient.cancelscheduledmessageasync?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-azure-servicebus-topicclient-cancelscheduledmessageasync(system-int64)). Though I am not sure if you can easily achieve what you describe in the rest of your question. Maybe [duplicate detection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/duplicate-detection) can also help you there, but it would prevent the second set of messages, not the first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply on this post, I saw this method but how do I know the sequence number of the message to delete/cancel them. As the messages in my case are published by a different consumer and different internal process is trying to cancel them

Comment: I was going through this example, and this example helps to read the scheduled messages, but the problem I do find is iterating through all the scheduled messages in the topic which would be a memory & compute-intensive operation if there are a million records in the topic.

https://www.drware.com/azure-service-bus-peek-delete-scheduled-message-which-has-future-enqueue-time/

Comment: Your initial question was if it is possible to delete messages from a topic like it is possible for a queue. The sequence number behavior is identical for topics and queues as far as I know. If you have multiple questions, you should split them so they are easier to answer. I suggest you use a separate question to tackle other options of handling these scheduled messages.